# An ugly formula

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, algebra

Our teacher wrote the following ugly algebraic formula on the blackboard
$$(n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^{4/3}+(n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^{-4/3}$$
Our teacher told us that for some positive integers $n$ this ugly formula has integer value! Then our teacher asked us: "What is the largest integer value below 1 million that can be produced by putting a positive integers $n$ in this formula?" Now I ask you: Can you find the answer?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code: If this is simple then please please please please please show us how you do this!!!!

Comment: @Haobin computers are not allowed?

Comment: The tag no-computers is A puzzle designed to be solved without using calculators or computers.

Comment: Personally, I'd guess that the answer is 2, obtained when n=1 and the teacher is laughing right now.

Comment: >! $x=n+\sqrt{n^2-1}$ is a solution to $x+1/x=2n$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Tony Ruth's answer provides this alternate form of the equation:

> $16n^4 - 16n^2 + 2 = m^3 -3m$

Adding 2 to both sides and factoring,

> $(4n^2-2)^2=(m-1)^2(m+2)$

Then

> $m+2=(\frac{4n^2-2}{m-1})^2=x^2$ (with $x>0$, and $x$ integer)

Substituting this back in,

> $x^2(x^2-3)^2=(4n^2-2)^2$

So

> $x(x^2-3)=4n^2-2$ (both sides are positive)

Add 2 to both sides again:

> $(x-1)^2(x+2)=(2n)^2$

So

> $x+2=(\frac{2n}{x-1})^2=y^2$ (with $y>0$, and $y$ integer)

And

> $y(y^2-3)=2n$ (again, with both sides positive)

For every $y>1$, this is true for some integer $n$, so we can choose the $y$ that gives the biggest value of $m$ less than 1 million. This is:

> $y=\lfloor\sqrt[4]{1,000,000}\rfloor=31$
> $m=(y^2-2)^2-2=919,679$
> $n=\frac{y(y^2-3)}{2}=14,849$.

So the answer is

> $919,679$

Answer (score 6):

**Partial solution.** I can reduce this to a polynomial equation with only integral powers, but so far I am not sure how to find the integer solutions of this new equation.

New equation:

> $16n^4 - 16n^2 + 2 = m^3 -3m$

where m < 1,000,000

> This is a depressed cubic equation for m, I tried setting $16n^4 - 16n^2 + 2=q$ and solving the depressed cubic, and I get a new ugly equation $m = (\frac{q + \sqrt{q^2-4}}{2})^\frac{1}{3} + (\frac{2}{q + \sqrt{q^2-4}})^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Here is how I derived the new equation.

> Square the original equation $$(n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^\frac{8}{3} + (n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^\frac{-8}{3} + 2 = m^2 $$

Then

> Move the 2 over and multiple this equation by the original equation. $$ (n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^4 + (n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^{-4} + (n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^\frac{4}{3} + (n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^\frac{-4}{3} = m^3 - 2m $$

Substitute

> $$ (n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^4 + (n+\sqrt{n^2-1})^{-4} = m^3 - 3m $$

Then to remove the radicals.

> Multiply by $$(\frac{n-\sqrt{n^2-1}}{n-\sqrt{n^2-1}})^4$$ and create a like denominator

You get,

> $$(\frac{(n+\sqrt{n^2-1})*(n^2-(n^2-1))}{n^2-(n^2-1)})^4+(\frac{(n-\sqrt{n^2-1})}{n^2-(n^2-1)})^4$$

Then

> The $n^2-(n^2-1)$ terms are just 1. Finally you expand out the powers and all the terms with radicals cancel.

Comment: If you say that (4n²-1)²'s a constant, then you get an equation of the type m³ - pm = q, from there you could try [solving the depressed cubic](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac11/fac11.html)

Comment: @Gamow, Thanks, I had made an algebra error. I updated the equation.

Comment: Can you explain how you factorised it to get the new equation?

Comment: @user230452 I added the derivation. It's fairly straightforward. Finding $m^3-3m$ removes the $\frac{4}{3}$ power. Then conjugate to get rid of the radical.